# Can some please help me identify this bike with a picture of the frame that i have. Thank you

Tags: identify-this-bike

I have this bike frame that my buddy left behind at my house.  I was wonderinng if anyone could possibly help me identify the make and model?  Thank you in advance for helping me. I have the serial number if that helps at all. [image]

Comment: Can you ask your buddy to take their stuff away?   Or ask them for all the rest of the bike parts?   Or whether it even belonged to them in the first place ?

Comment: V Brake posts with no discs, steep head tube and seat tube (Almost parallel), single pivot with asymmetric rear triangle has me thinking a 'quality' mid to late 1990s bike rather than a 2000's BSO.

Comment: Shock mounted above top tube is 'interesting' and such a design uniqueness is not common on cheap bikes (the copy what has been shown to work). Should be easy frame to confirm an ID if you find a match. Could easily be a custom build/home build/prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be from a mid-2000's full-suspension MTB of some sort.

It appears to lack disk brake mounts while having V-brake bosses.

Sadly there are a lot of parts missing.  If you have the fork and suspension components somewhere, that will help a rebuild significantly.

Observe that the right-hand chainstay is significantly dropped, suggesting it was built for wide tyres at the time.

I can't comment on the geometry of the suspension, hopefully others here can expand on that point.

The serial number is generally useless unless you already know the brand, AND that brand had some format to their numbers which was understood.   Serials are not like automotive VINs.

Comment: "*Observe that the ... at the time*". Why does a dropped right-hand help with/allow for wide tyres?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke The two chainstays are nor symmetric, which means more width is available for the rear tyre, at the place where the right-side crank arm passes the chainstay.  Hard to put into words.     Check out https://www.bikehugger.com/posts/mark-v-and-the-tale-of-the-dropped-chainstay/   for lots of photos.